# Test Soap webservice using jmeter with http request

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, jmeter

i have a question for you guys, do you know a way how can i send http request with jmeter to my soap webservice(jax-ws library)?. I have a problem to point server name or ip(its localhost so should it be loopback?) and path. I'm using glassfish4 as my web server. I do not want to use option SOAP/XML RPC Request, because when i use it with my web service i can't see that any data have been sent(it's always 0 -in fact maybe you have idea why is that...it's also a solution to my problem because i need http request to see how much data i've sent)
!https://postimg.org/image/mpbai5n1v/
Thanks in advance
Regards!

Comment: Take a look at SoapUI - tool designed for testing SOAP Webservices. It will generate requests for you from the wsdl contract. No point in using raw HTTP request here

Comment: thx, im using soap ui also but there are only bytes which were send i need both: data which client send to server and data from respond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- [Http Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) and fill in:

  - Server Name or IP
  - IP if different from 443 or 80
  - Protocol if https
- Add a [Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) under it with :

> Content-Type=text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   [image]

Note there is a template that lets you easily create this, see screenshot:

[image]

Finally I suggest you read this tutorial:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, im trying to do the way you suggest, but i have problems with path(server name or ip field, path field in SOAP http request) .Maybe you have idea where those paths should be?